# javascript executed from server side in java?

Tags: java, javascript

I was looking for real information about this, I am working some system on Java EE, I worked all my life on web, now I am getting into systems, my boss told me he makes javascripts works from "server side" to manage polls and stuffs, still I didnt think was right and I told him I thought javascript was only executed client-side, still seems like its right, I found both information about saying it is possible and it is not, anyone has some valid answer about this? and if yes, how is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIR MS IIS can run JScript.

Comment: You can run javascript inside java... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scripting API is in the javax.script package available in the Java SE 6 platform.

Refer Link :-

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed execute JavaScript on the server-side with third-party packages like [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), [Mozilla Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino), or similar.

However, it's unclear to me from your description whether he wants you to actually *execute* JavaScript from the server-side, *serve* JavaScript content from the server-side, or use AJAX to *make remote-procedure calls* to server-side code.

Comment: yeah! thats exactly what I told him.. but he treated me like an dumb front of all, so , I decided to dont say more things...I dont understand, because they are showing some dialog box and stuffs like that, for me seems not necessary

Comment: You'll need to clarify further with your boss as to which, specifically, he means.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute javascript on server side too which means that develop server centric code on server side for etsblishing connection, serving HTML files etc.All these things can be done on using server side javascript.There are so many frameworks that are used to achieve this.The main objective of running serve side javascript is to execute server side functionalities.One such example is maintinaing long-lived connections with the client.

Nod.js is such a framework which is used to implement the above said functionality.Apart from this, there are other server side javascript frameworks as well.RhinoJS is can be used to execute execute javascript in server side when running in a Java Virtual machine.

However,the idea using the server side javascript frameowork will vary depending upon your requirements.